# why compiler doesn’t provide the default constructor when a class contains any parameterized constructor?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

**Why java compiler doesn't provide the default constructor when a class contains any parameterized constructor.**

Comment: Because this would mean that every class could be constructed without parameterization, and this is not desirable. Classes might depend upon others objects and primitives in order to work.

Answer (score 2):

Because if you explicitly define a constructor, then you're saying something about how a class instance should be instantiated. You want this to be rigidly defined, and a default constructor would work around this.

Java provides a default constructor when none other is defined as a convenience. But if you start defining your own, it has no purpose and is removed.